# Casting a String to a Symbol in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I've created an anonymous PLSQL block to test and I'm running into an issue with the formatting.

```
set serveroutput ON

BEGIN
  FOR I IN (SELECT DISTINCT do.SUBOBJECT_NAME from dba_objects do WHERE do.object_name='MY_TABLE' AND do.OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE PARTITION') LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(I.subobject_name);

    SELECT
      t.field
    INTO
        some_var
    FROM
      MY_TABLE PARTITION(I.subobject_name) t;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

However I get several compilation errors, which I believe are related to the fact that `I.subobject_name` is a string. I believe the `PARTITION` function wants an actual partition symbol(proper term for this?), but I can't give it in this loop.

Is there any kind of casting function that can perform what I'm looking for?

Comment: Maybe use an execute immediate statement instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Partition* **IS NOT A FUNCTION**. Partition is [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2105152)
2. In your context your whole statement is static , thus you **CANNOT** pass partition name into it; partition name must be specified at compile time.
3. You can re-create your statement dynamically and then pass partition name in the loop - 
   a-la you are doing it. Just make sure you will concatenate string and not use bind variables, or your statement at run time won't be parsed and won't run.

Name for the symbol is *table partition*

Comment: Thanks for the lessons. Sorry, my PL/SQL is rusty on the naming. I ended up just doing a dynamic string and executing it via EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.